# How do I get a variable's value from one script and import it in another script?

Tags: environment-variables, variable

How do I get a variable's value from one script and import it in another script? But the catch is that the script where I am going to get the variable's value has also some commands that I don't want to run:

Let's say this is script1.sh:

```
variable="Hello"
#some command here e.g. yum check-update
```

And in script2.sh:

```
echo $var
```

I've found an approach where one uses the EXPORT command and puts ./script1.sh inside the script2.sh but it runs the other commands.

So, how can I get the variable's value without running the commands inside it? I hope this question is clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarize, you want to retrieve a value out of `script1.sh` without running all the commands in `script1.sh`.  I will assume that `script1.sh` is not under your control, possibly because it is vendor-provided, or managed by an obstinate colleague, or similar such issue, which makes it so that `script1.sh` has to be used as is.

I will present two approaches.  The first is good for getting specific variables out of `script1.sh`, one at time:

```
var=$(awk -F'"' '/^variable=/ {print $2}' script1.sh )
echo $var
```

This uses `awk` to read (not execute, just read) `script1.sh`.  `awk` looks for the line that begins with `variable=` and then writes what appears after the double-quote mark on that line.  The output from `awk` is capture into variable `var`.

In more detail:

- The statement is of the form `var=$(...)`.  This means that whatever is in the parentheses is run as a bash command and its standard output is assigned to the variable `var`.
- Inside the parentheses, we have the `awk` command: `awk -F'"' '/^variable=/ {print $2}' script1.sh`.  Let us consider it in parts.
- `awk` breaks lines (records) into fields.  `-F'"'` tells awk to use double-quote as a field separator.
- `/^variable=/` tells `awk` to restrict operation to lines that begin with `variable=`.  Thus, all the miscellaneous commands in `script1.sh` will be ignored.
- `{print $2}` tells `awk` to print the second field.  This means whatever is between the first and second occurence of a double-quote character.
- The last argument to `awk` tells it what file to read: `script1.sh`.

The above approach is good for handling one variable at a time and allows you to rename the variable if you like.

#### How to handle many variables

If you want to source all the variables assigned in `script1.sh`, consider:

```
source <(grep -E '^\w+=' script1.sh)
```

This uses `grep` to extract all lines from `script1.sh` that look like variable assignments.  These lines are then run in the current shell, assigning the variables.

If you use this approach first check to make sure that you want all the variables and that there aren't any that will interfere with what you are doing.  If there are such, we can exclude them with a second `grep` command.

Considering the pieces in turn:

- `source file` tells the shell to execute the `file` in the current shell.
- `<(...)` is called process substitution.  It allows us to use the output of a command in place of a file name.
- The command `grep -E '^\w+=' script1.sh` extracts all lines that seem like variable assignments.  If you run this command by itself on the command line, you should see something like:

  ```
  variable="Hello"
  var2="Value2"
  ```

  and so on.  You should do this first and inspect the output to make sure that these are the lines that you want to execute.

Comment: This approach works. Thanks, @John1024! Do you have another approach but with lesser characters? I'm going to use like, 200+ variables.

Comment: @MiguelRoque OK.  Answer updated.

Comment: source <(grep -E '\w+=' script1.sh) works! Thanks again, @John1024!

Comment: Note that because you don't _anchor_ it, `grep -E '\w+='` is equivalent to `grep '\w='` and would match on `configure --prefix=/opt/foo` or `echo foo=bar` for instance. You may want to be a bit more restrictive, like in `grep -E '^[[:blank:]]*[_[:alnum:]]+='` (note that `\w` is not portable). That's still no fool-proof but probably more reliable. The next big issue would be lines like `ENVVAR=value some-command...`

Answer (score 4):

You should do this with three scripts:

```
cat ./script/init_vars.sh
    variable_1=value_1
    variable_2=value_2
    variable_3=value_3

cat ./script/module_1.sh
    . ./script/init_vars.sh
    printf %s\\n "$variable_1"

cat ./script/module_2.sh
    . ./script/init_vars.sh
    printf %s\\n "$variable_1"
```

If your files looked like ***^that^*** then you'd be able to do this a lot easier - without relying on regexes. Running either `module_1.sh` or `module_2.sh` would output:

```
value_1
```

Comment: My problem is that all of my variables and commands are inside one script. Nevertheless, I tried implementing your code. It works, too! Thanks @mikeserv.

Comment: @MiguelRoque - well, then maybe you should use regexes - but just *once* to get something like this. Then go through and check it to make sure it'll work and stick to the modular scheme from then on. Otherwise - and this is the real problem with the other solutions - you're doomed to break script 2 everytime you modify script 1. It's about as brittle as you can get. And what if `$var1` is defined twice in script 1 like: `var1=something ; test "$var1" ||\nvar1=something_else`? What value do you get then?

Answer (score -1):

Use `source` to read the file variable in another shell file.

Suppose your variable `var1` is initialised in `/pathtoFile1/file1.sh`

`var1='Sridhar'`

In another script `file2.sh`:

```
source /pathtoFile1/file1.sh
var2=$var1
```

Now `var2` contains `var1` value

Comment: Sourcing `file1.sh` will execute any commands in it.  The OP specifically stated that they don't want that to happen.