# How to assign a variable from another variable in a separate file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a file with a bunch of variables such as:

**file**

```
DEVICE0_USB="usbSerialNo1"
DEVICE1_USB="usbSerialNo2"
```

and I want to assign the contents of any of these variables to variables in a script, for instance:

**script**

```
FAX_MACHINE_USB=$DEVICE0_USB
COFFEE_MAKER_USB=$DEVICE1_USB
```

so that when I `echo` `$FAX_MACHINE_USB` I receive `usbSerialNo1`

I can use `source` to get the variables from **file** but this will also run every line in **file**. In my case it's not a problem since **file** has only variable declarations, but I still prefer not to do it. Is there another way of achieving it?

Comment: The common practice is to source it. Why do you not want to do so?

Comment: You can use `file` to replace the variables in `script` without executing `file` following [this question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/how-to-perform-replacements-defined-in-one-file-on-another-file)

Comment: Quote your variables when you use them. So `FAX_MACHINE_USB="$DEVICE0_USB"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems a similar question was answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136152/209558).

You can of course use `.` or `source` to assign the variables if you are comfortable, but you can also use `awk` or `grep` to only run specific lines from the file that *look* like variable declerations.

> #### How to handle many variables
>
> If you want to source all the variables assigned in `script1.sh`,
>   consider:
>
> ```
> source <(grep -E '^\w+=' script1.sh)
> ```
>
> This uses `grep` to extract all lines from `script1.sh` that look like
>   variable assignments.  These lines are then run in the current shell,
>   assigning the variables.
>
> If you use this approach first check to make sure that you want all
>   the variables and that there aren't any that will interfere with what
>   you are doing.  If there are such, we can exclude them with a second
>   `grep` command.
>
> Considering the pieces in turn:
>
> - `source file` tells the shell to execute the `file` in the current shell.
> - `<(...)` is called process substitution.  It allows us to use the output of a command in place of a file name.
> - The command `grep -E '^\w+=' script1.sh` extracts all lines that seem like variable assignments.  If you run this command by itself on
>     the command line, you should see something like:
>
>   ```
>   variable="Hello"
>   var2="Value2"
>   ```
>
>   and so on.  You should do this first and inspect the output to make sure that these are the lines that you want to execute.